# PhoneGap destinationType property is returning the incorrect file uri

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am using PhoneGap + Sencha Touch on an application. I have managed to take a picture and upload to a server. I am having a problem selecting a picture from the photolibrary.

```
selectPicture: function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.uploadPicture.bind(this), this.getPictureError.bind(this), {
      // camera options
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });
  }
```

I think there is something wrong with the destinationType property. In my uploadPicture function the imageURI is returning a directory like: 'content://media/external/images/media/[some random number]'.

I thought the imageURI should be something like: 'file://storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/myimage.jpg'

I tried using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI and it works fine if you are taking a picture, but not when selecting a picture. Here is my code when I want to select a picture form the photolibrary (I am using sencha touch 2):

```
selectPicture: function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.resolveFileURI.bind(this), this.getPictureError.bind(this), {
      // camera options
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });
},

resolveFileURI: function (entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(entry, this.uploadPicture.bind(this), this.fail.bind(this));
},

uploadPicture: function (entry) {
    console.log(entry.fullPath)
}
```

According to logcat I don't even make it into the resolveFileURI function. In fact my application crashes. The error in logcat is:

10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=17, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/584 }} to activity {com.dwmobile.android/com.dwmobile.android.AndroidSencha}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3141)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher.onActivityResult(CameraLauncher.java:453)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:823)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
10-23 14:39:24.552: E/AndroidRuntime(2975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)

Comment: make sure phonegap is working?

Comment: Phonegap is working. I am using phonegap all over the place in my app and this is this one place where it is not working. I can also take a picture and upload it just fine. When I select a picture from the photolibrary is where I get into to trouble.

Comment: try change phonegap version. My app using sencha touch 2 and phonegap 1.5. It work ok with camare and library.

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: cordova-2.0.0 is the version.

Comment: I think the file I was choosing was too bing. I tried selecting another file and it worked just fine. I also added some checks in the  resolveLocalFileSystemURI success before doing the upload such as entry.isFile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct on Android. You are able to use the content URI's to set the image source attribute. You can even pass that uri into [FileTransfer.upload](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_upload). However, if you want to get a real file type uri then send it into [window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem_resolve_local_file_system_uri_quick_example) and the success callback will give you the file path.